# Child node of a heap

Tags: data-structures, heap

What is the index of a child node in a heap in the array represenatation of a heap.
In my lecture notes and [in this article](http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/heapSort.htm)

it is given as `2k` and/or `2k+1`

But in an array indexes start from 0,not 1 right?
Therefore shouldn't the children of node k be `2k+1` and/or `2k+2`

Comment: Well,as per array index it should be `2k+1` and `2k+2`. But,it's the general convention of considering the root as 1st element and proceeding next to child roots as `2k` and `2k+1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well as per going from general convention that the `array indices usually start from 0`.So in this case the root is assigned the 0th node.Then the child nodes are considered as `2k+1` and `2k+2`;

But,even in the article they have clearly mentioned that

> **The root of the tree A[1]** and given index i of a node, the indices of
>   its parent, left child and right child can be computed

```
 PARENT (i)
     return floor(i/2)
 LEFT (i)
     return 2i
 RIGHT (i)
     return 2i + 1
```

Hence,going as per the article,it should be `2k` and `2k+1`. Had the root been considered as index 0 of the array, then the indices of child nodes will be `2k+1` and `2k+2`;

Answer (score 0):

If the indices start from 0 it is `2k+1` and/or `2k+2`.
If they start from 1, it is `2k` and `2k + 1`.